# ASP VBScript If Statements

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I trying to create an if statement in ASP/VBScript that will look like the following

```
if ConditionToTest then
    //first statment to execute
    //second statment to exexute
ElseIf DifferentConditionToTest then 
    //first statment to execute
    //second statment to exexute
End If
```

The problem is a get various errors from asking for another End If to it simply not executing the second ElseIF. Does ASP/VBScript support multiple statements inside an if like above and if so if there a special way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is correct.  In your real code, check to make sure that "ElseIf" is one word, and that you correctly balance If with End If, Do While with Loop, For with Next, etc.

Also, you cannot use "//" as comments in VBScript.

If you're still stuck, please post your code.

Comment: When balancing End Ifs with Ifs should for example in the above there be two End Ifs for that routine. So essentially one for the If and one for the ElseIf, and if there should be two would they both go at the end or the first go before the ElseIf

Comment: Nevermind. Found the problem was that although you don't need two end ifs for a elseif statement I have a couple of statements (out of the 20 I have in the function) that are nested ifs rather than elseif which is where the error had occurred as I never had matching end Ifs